# Duplicate row based on specific conditions in column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

As input I have a table like this example:

| ID_EXAMPLE | KRED_NUMMER | SYSTEM | BUKRS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 100506 | PPL | 0002 (PG 1030);#1025;#1340 |
| **2** | 1656082 | PASM | 3333 |
| **3** | 1656099 | DFMG | 0716;#6008;#6104 |

And as you can see last column BUKRS can have different value formats. And I'd like for each code (4 digits) in BUKRS to create a separate row, but with the same values in other columns. Based on 2 conditions:

- duplicate row for first 4 digits in BUKRS (if there is a string in the brackets, ignore it)
- duplicate row for each 4 digits in BUKRS after #

The expected result:

| ID_EXAMPLE | KRED_NUMMER | SYSTEM | BUKRS | My Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 100506 | PPL | 0002 | always take first 4 digits in BUKRS |
| **1** | 100506 | PPL | 1025 | 4 digits after each # (after first #) |
| **1** | 100506 | PPL | 1340 | 4 digits after each # (after second #) |
| **2** | 1656082 | PASM | 3333 | always take first 4 digits in field |
| **3** | 1656099 | DFMG | 0716 | always take first 4 digits in field |
| **3** | 1656099 | DFMG | 6008 | 4 digits after each # (after first #) |
| **3** | 1656099 | DFMG | 6104 | 4 digits after each # (after second #) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and a short regex to get the numbers, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
out = (df
 .assign(BUKRS=df['BUKRS'].str.findall(r'(?:^|#)(\d{4})'))
 .explode('BUKRS')
)
```

output:

```
   ID_EXAMPLE  KRED_NUMMER SYSTEM BUKRS
0           1       100506    PPL  0002
0           1       100506    PPL  1025
0           1       100506    PPL  1340
1           2      1656082   PASM  3333
2           3      1656099   DFMG  0716
2           3      1656099   DFMG  6008
2           3      1656099   DFMG  6104
```

Comment: What does this pattern `?:` mean? It doesn't look like lookbehind.

Comment: @MykolaZotko this is a non-capturing group, unfortunately you can't use a lookbehind with a non-fixed pattern

Comment: @mozway could you please help me again? Format of data changed, now instead of # I have an empty space, for example = 0002 (PG 1030); 1025; 1340. How should I change it?

Comment: you can't only match an empty space, this would match all numbers, you have to better define the logic

Comment: Instead of # I added [ ] and it works. Thx :)